# Append Variable To String

Tags: powershell

Can you append a variable to the beginning of a string?  I have tried, unsuccessfully to accomplish this.  In my sample below, I get the literal value returned, not the two variables combined.

```
$FileName = "Test.xlsx"
$startoffile = "C:\Tremble\"
Write-Host $startoffile'FileName'

#This prints the literal so what I see in my window is
#$ startoffileFileName

#My desired output to be seen in the window is
#C:\Tremble\Test.xlsx
```

Comment: powershell uses the plus sign (`+`)as a string concatenator. `"$startoffile" + "$FileName"`

Comment: @FrankThomas and it also didnt help that I omitted the $ from the start of my variable FileName in my Write-Host statement.

Comment: well, there is that... ;-) but the concatenation operator works the same either way; you can concatenate vars or literals in whatever combos you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1:

```
$FileName = "Test.xlsx"
$startoffile = "C:\Tremble\"
Write-Host ($startoffile + $Filename)
```

Output:

```
C:\Tremble\Test.xlsx
```

Method 2

```
$FileName = "Test.xlsx"
$startoffile = "C:\Tremble\"
#Write-Host ($startoffile + $Filename)

-join ($startoffile, $FileName), " "
```

Output:

```
C:\Tremble\Test.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Write-Host "$startoffile$FileName"
```

Note the double quotes. Any variables in a double-quoted string will be expanded.

Another possibility is to use Join-Path:

```
Write-Host (Join-Path $startoffile $FileName)
```